# OpenGL screenshot taking too much time on android?

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, vuforia

I am using OpenGL render method to capture screenshot.but take it takes 7 to 8 seconds on NEXUS 7 to read pixel information. I am using this code to read pixel information and save it as Bitmap.

```
 public Bitmap grabPixels(GL10 mGL) {

        final int mWidth = mViewWidth;
        final int mHeight = mViewHeight;

        IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
        IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
        mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

        for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
                ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
            }
        }

        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);
        return mBitmap;

}
```

How can i increase speed of reading the pixel information and convert it into the Bitmap ?

Comment: Did you measure which of your command takes the time? Reading the pixels or storing the bitmap?

Comment: @BDL Storing the bitmap takes too much time
following code takes too much time :-
 for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
                ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
            }
        }

Comment: I would then edit the question to "why does storing an image in android take that long" and edit out all of the OpenGL-es things since they seem unrelated. It could get you a higher attention because people immediately see that no OpenGL knowledge is required. (This is just a recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

*[I wrote another answer about saving GIFs on gamedev, which might be useful.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/139486/34057)*

You can't call `glReadPixels()` on another thread. But it's most likely (as you said) the process of saving the image that takes the majority of time. As such the solution is to do the saving on a separate thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ... save screenshot ...
    }
}).start();
```

*Before anybody comes at me with pitchforks.* Then yes you *can* call `glReadPixels()` on another thread. It however requires a shared context, which can be specified when calling [eglCreateContext()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateContext.xhtml).

```
EGLContext shared = ...
EGLDisplay display = ...
EGLConfig eglConfig = ...

int[] attrib_list = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, shared, attrib_list);
```

But before you start digging into shared contexts (which can be a pain in themselves) then make sure your bottleneck isn't the saving the image, which it most likely is.